# Why Google Analytics Admin Api (GA4) is missing from google apis-explorer?

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-apis-explorer, google-analytics-4

Why [Analytics Admin Api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1) is missing from [apis-explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer)  ?

[image: 3]

Comment: Thats a good question, I will flag that with the team.

Comment: In the mean time you can use the [Try Me](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1/rest/v1beta/accounts/list?apix=true)